How to set IsReadOnly property using Binding in WPF?
I have such XAML:
                    <DataGrid DataContext="{Binding Path=Groups[0]}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FactorGroupList}"
                              AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False"
                              Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" RowHeaderWidth="0" 
                              BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent"
                          >
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Фактор" Width="*" Binding="{Binding FactorName}"/>
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Знач. (%)" Width="70" Binding="{Binding FactorValue}" IsReadOnly="{Binding isChild}"/>
                            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Активен" Width="70" Binding="{Binding FactorVisible}"/>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>

I want to make cells IsReadOnly=true by binding it to bool object's property isChild.
This IsReadOnly="{Binding isChild}" doesn't work.
Is there any way to do so that the cell is only editable if the object field is false?

You can always use a DataGridTemplateColumn to get full control over the created control(s) and their binding.
